# How to read a 5-byte thing into a `Word64` using `binary`?

Tags: haskell, binary-data, bytestring

Is it possible to read a 5-byte segment of data into a `Word64` using the `binary` package, leaving the three higher-order bits empty? Or must I use a `ByteString`?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: The question is absolutely OK, no need to close.

Comment: The question is rather unclear to me.  If the five bytes are not a byrestring then how are you wanting to use the binary package?  What higher order bites should remain empty?  61 62 63 or 37 38 and 39?

Comment: Also, what had stopped you from doing this?  Usually questions without an attempt are voted close for reasons such as "too broad".

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I can use and live with a bytestring, but just wondering if I could do C-style bit-packing with `binary`.

Comment: Ah so as @bergey said we could use Data.Bits or just plain old multiplication such as `toWord64 = foldl (\a c - >a*256 + fromIntegral c) 0 :: [Word8] -> Word64` and bitmasks can be applied as desired to ensure the right bits are zero.  If you want to use Binary then the implication is using bytestring, for example you could `decode . (pack [0,0,0] <>) :: ByteString -> Word64`.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I see. So I need to go through a ByteString absolutely, and in my case I'd just use the ByteString itself. The answer to _my_ question is no, then. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Shift and bitwise-OR are in [Data.Bits](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Bits.html).  Data.Binary.Get has a family of [getWord functions](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-0.8.6.0/docs/Data-Binary-Get.html#v:getWord64be) that read fixed-length pieces from a `ByteString` of unknown length, without any interpretation beyond endian-ness.  It may also help to know that `fromIntegral` for `Word` types preserves the unsigned-int interpretation of the Word (when going from smaller to larger words), so you can zero-extend a `Word8` to a `Word64`.